# I am trying to import:from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, BucketIterator,Iterator,data, but get error 'No module named 'torchtext.legacy'

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I am trying to execute the following code for a nlp proj

```
import torchtext
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, BucketIterator, Iterator
from torchtext.legacy import data


----> 6 from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, BucketIterator, Iterator
      7 from torchtext.legacy import data
      8 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchtext.legacy'.
```

I have tried it on both kaggle notebook and jupyter notebook and found the same error in both.
i even tried to install !pip install -qqq deepmatcher==0.1.1 in kaggle to solve the issue but it still gives the same error.
is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before you `import torchtext.legacy`, you need to `!pip install torchtext==0.10.0`.

Maybe legacy was removed in version 0.11.0.

Comment: I had the same problem. Downgrading torchtext to 0.10 fixed the problem. It seems that legacy is removed in version 0.11.0.

Answer (score 2):

torchtext.legacy is only for pytorch1.9+

for those who use lower version of pytorch (e.g. I use the pytorch1.6 + torchtext 0.6), you can revise the "train_ebr.py" script in the "fairseq" folders.

```
# old 
from torchtext.legacy import data, datasets
from torchtext.legacy.vocab import Vocab

# new
from torchtext import data, datasets
from torchtext.vocab import Vocab
```

Answer (score 1):

Use torchtext version v0.6 and corresponding compatibility version of torch.

`!pip install torchtext==0.6 torch==1.5` (In colab) Restart runtime after excuting this line

Then you can use

`from torchtext.data  import Field, TabularDataset, BucketIterator, Iterator`